# How to combine items in a list as one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, user-input

I'm just a bit confused on how to make my items in a list see several characters as one.  So far, the entire thing looks like:

```
classes=input("Enter your classes: " )
     def printsched(classes):
          for n in classes:
               print(n)
          return len(classes)
printsched(classes)
print(printsched(classes))
```

When I enter classes in the form of something like `["GE0 101", "PSY 101", "GER 104"]` I want it to print back out:

```
GEO 101
PSY 101
GER 104
```

See below to see what it gives me.  It sees each character as one item on the list.  I also need it to return the value of all the characters in the list, so in this example, I want it to be 21, but instead it gives me 34.  How can I fix it so GEO 101 and all the rest would be one item?

```
[
"
G
E
0
1
0
1
"
,

"
P
S
Y

1
0
1
"
,

"
G
E
R

1
0
4
"
]
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a `python-3.x` tag because you wouldn't be having this issue with Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

`input` always result in a single `str`. If you want to parse this string as being JSON-like you can use the `json` module.

```
import json

classes=json.loads(input("Enter your classes: " ))
def printsched(classes):
    for n in classes:
        print(n)
    return len("".join(classes))
printsched(classes)
```

For more user friendly input you can use the split function and trim function.

```
classes=[x.trim() for x in input("Enter your classes: " ).split(",")]
def printsched(classes):
    for n in classes:
        print(n)
    return len("".join(classes))
printsched(classes)
```

Note: do not add multiple things in a single method. The method will become cluttered and unclear. What is the single responsibility of this method, (printing or calculating the length of the input string)

```
classes=[x.trim() for x in input("Enter your classes: " ).split(",")]

def print_classes(classes):
    for n in classes:
        print(n)

def calc_length(classes
    return len("".join(classes))

print_classes(classes)
print(calc_length(classes))
```

Answer (score 0):

`classes = input("Enter your classes: ").strip('[""]').split('","')`

This should work

Answer (score -1):

**[Update]**

Use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of dangerous `eval()` (as Francis Colas pointed out in the comment)

```
import ast

classes=input("Enter your classes: " )

def printsched(classes):
    classes = ast.literal_eval(classes)
    for n in classes:
        print(n)
    return len(classes)

printsched(classes)
```

**[Original]**

<strike>I suggest simply using `eval()` as follows:</strike>

```
classes=input("Enter your classes: " )

def printsched(classes):
    classes = eval(classes)
    for n in classes:
        print(n)
    return len(classes)

printsched(classes)
```

Comment: Please don't suggest `eval` as a solution for, well, anything really.

Comment: `eval` is indeed a dangerous proposition. However, in some cases, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can do the job.

Comment: Thanks @Francis Colas for your comment. I know `eval()` is dangerous, but I simply thought that OP is novice for Python. That was my fault.